# Dropdownlist in Auto Generated column in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

Having a datatable which returns different number of columns on different occasions (As per Data Feeded)

My datatable dt pertains start time, endtime and the number of days the school will work(i.e, monday, tuesday)

For example:

For 4th std:
datatable is:

**StartTime | EndTime | Monday | Wednesday | Thursday**

```
   7:10 | 8:00

   8:00 | 9:00

   9:00 | 10:00
```

For 6th std, it is like:

**StartTime | EndTime  | Thursday**

```
   7:20 | 8:00

   8:00 | 8:40

   8:40 | 9:20
```

Am binding this to a GRIDVIEW

Now my question is, in the days column, i want to bind two dropdownlist for subject and faculty.
So how to bind it.

Without using template field,is there any way that i can bind dropdownlist in auto generated columns? Or if i use template field, my days are tentative(i.e, sometimes monday-friday,sometimes only wednesday

In short, the days side is tentative, so any suggestions?
I want to bind 2 dropdown in days section

Any help will be appreciated
thnx

Comment: Why you need drop down. Can user change day, like from Monday to Wednesday?

Comment: uhhh,,its a timetable,,,,the schema is being submitted by HEAD(Principal).He sends that on this following days,6th or 8th std will have classes.So,user cant change days,but can only fill subjects and faculty details.Thnx 4 reply

Comment: please see this it may help you creating dynamic fields from code behind http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-TemplateField-Column-dynamically-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx. I would have gave you extra help if I knew how you are planning to save data.

Comment: ok,,,sorry to all,,,i got the solution,,i had just used the loop which helped me adding days section (monday,tuesday etc) in gridview and used VISIBLE=FALSE property..thnks all for help

Comment: Black Baron,I tried your link,,and it really helped me :) ,,,thnx a lot,,wish i could thank in any other way.thank u so much

Comment: @user2177138 glad it worked for you :) I'll post the link as an answer so that other users may benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can create any template fields or bound fields dynamically from code behind using the GridView's OnRowDataBound.

See this link has a good example on how to do it: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-TemplateField-Column-dynamically-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx